# Silverlight Data Grid: Is it possible to DataGridCell's content cover the whole row?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, datagrid, styles

So, i got a different issue. In silverlight data grid for rows satisfying a condition i want to do following:

Suppose that my grid have 9 columns,

I want my first 3 cell content stay same. The fourth cell in this row contains a very long text and i want it to cover rest of the row.

Well i've tried following in grid's LoadingRow event

```
        FrameworkElement fe = sender.Columns[3].GetCellContent(e.Row);
        FrameworkElement fe4 = sender.Columns[4].GetCellContent(e.Row);
        FrameworkElement fe5 = sender.Columns[5].GetCellContent(e.Row);
        FrameworkElement fe6 = sender.Columns[6].GetCellContent(e.Row);
        FrameworkElement fe7 = sender.Columns[7].GetCellContent(e.Row);
        FrameworkElement fe8 = sender.Columns[8].GetCellContent(e.Row);

        DataGridCell result = fe.Parent as DataGridCell;
        DataGridCell result4 = fe4.Parent as DataGridCell;
        DataGridCell result5 = fe5.Parent as DataGridCell;
        DataGridCell result6 = fe6.Parent as DataGridCell;
        DataGridCell result7 = fe7.Parent as DataGridCell;
        DataGridCell result8 = fe8.Parent as DataGridCell;

        result.Width = 1000;
        fe.Width = 1000;
        //result4.Content = null;
        //result5.Content = null;
        //result6.Content = null;
        //result7.Content = null;
        //result8.Content = null;

        result4.Width = 0;
        result5.Width = 0;
        result6.Width = 0;
        result7.Width = 0;
        result8.Width = 0;

        (fe as TextBlock).Text = "There's some long text here...";

        //(fe4 as TextBlock).Text = string.Empty;
        //(fe5 as TextBlock).Text = string.Empty;
        //(fe6 as TextBlock).Text = string.Empty;
        //(fe7 as TextBlock).Text = string.Empty;
        //(fe8 as TextBlock).Text = string.Empty;
```

This code's not working the width of the cell always be equal to the width of column. So how can i set this kind of cell merging? Is it possible?

Comment: You can not merge cells on silverlight datagrid.. you either have to change the column width or set it to Auto.

Comment: well i have managed to merge all cells in a row using row style by instead of cells i put a TextBlock in row template but i don't want this, i want first three cell stay same and fourth cell become last cell like colSpan in html. I found some third party components can manage cell merging both horizontal and vertical so there must be a way to achieve this.